# Designing the REST WEB API - Authorization in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I would like to design the Rest API for authorization. Users have operation level permission.

- Modules -- Example - Inventory
- Transactions - Example - Purchase Order
- Operations - Create, Edit, Delete, List, Print

My authentication is token based and I have stored the operation level permission for the user in the back-end. API supposed to provide - whether user has access permission for the module, transaction and operations for each form in my front end which is in Angular.

I will have to enable/disable the button in the front-end.

How do we design this?

One simple way is to call the API for each form to grab the permission. Is there any better way to handle this? I am using asp.net core web API and Angular in the front-end.

Thanks

Comment: You can create "authorization" filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2  and put your authorization code there to avoid doing it in every action.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your suggestion. Let me have a look